# Is there a complete list of S3 object metadata?

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata

I have a bunch of files in an S3 bucket. I need to go through them and add some metadata, for which I'm using the [node client](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js). The S3 api does not make this as easy as you might like. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html):

> Note that if you choose to update any of the object's
>   user-configurable metadata (system or user-defined) during the copy,
>   then you must explicitly specify all of the user-configurable metadata
>   present on the source object in your request, even if you are only
>   changing only one of the metadata values.

Fine, but that only works if you have the complete list of metadata that an S3 object can have. I found [this list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) but it's not complete. For example, it doesn't contain `ContentType`. If I load an object up with as much stuff as I can think to put on there I get this:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket --key some-file
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes", 
    "ContentType": "video/mp4", 
    "LastModified": "Sat, 18 May 2019 18:18:50 GMT", 
    "ContentLength": 50957711, 
    "VersionId": "null", 
    "ETag": "\"2d8a6acea8c37217a034d841084c6727-4\"", 
    "StorageClass": "ONEZONE_IA", 
    "ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", 
    "CacheControl": "cc", 
    "SSEKMSKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:999999999999:key/99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999", 
    "Metadata": {
        "val1": "test1", 
        "val2": "test2"
    }
}
```

Is that the whole list? I have no idea and I can't find any documentation. Also what happens if aws decides to add more system metadata later?

I also tried copying the existing head like this:

```
const p1 = { Bucket: bucket, Key: obj.Key, CopySource: `${bucket}/${obj.Key}`, MetadataDirective: 'REPLACE' };
const p2 = Object.assign(p1, head, { Metadata: { prop1: 'val1' } });
await s3.copyObject(p2).promise();
```

This resulted in errors like this:

> - UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ContentLength' found in params

since certain system metadata is read-only. I could simply do this

```
delete p2.ContentLength
```

but that has a similar problem since I don't know what other read-only metadata they might introduce in the future. At least I don't have to know all the existing metadata items though.

Or if there is an alternative approach to doing this that would be fine. Hopefully someone has come up with a more reasonable way to handle this.

Comment: I think the documentation is suggesting that you **retrieve the existing metadata** on that specific object, then "copy the object to itself" while specifying the previous metadata plus anything you wish to add.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ActuallyI tried that approach but it gave me errors about metadata items that weren't allowed (e.g. ContentLength). I could delete them but it's kind of the same problem in reverse. I'll update the post to contain that info though.